# Flutter ScrollView at whole Scaffold body

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have `ListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView` but if my list have a little elements, my ListView do not cover whole body of `Scaffold`, and cut elements while try scrolling. How to fix it?

Here is simplified code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:s/views/widgets/bottom_nav_dashboard.dart';

class PgVisit extends GetView {
  PgVisit({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scroll'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: myBottomNavigationBar(context, bBarType.simpleBack),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("A"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("B"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("C"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `shrinkWrap` and the `SingleChildScrollView` wrapper.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scroll'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return ListView(
            children: [
              const ListTile(
                title: Text("A"),
                subtitle: Text("A"),
              ),
              const ListTile(
                title: Text("B"),
                subtitle: Text("A"),
              ),
              const ListTile(
                title: Text("C"),
                subtitle: Text("A"),
              ),
              const ListTile(
                title: Text("C"),
                subtitle: Text("A"),
              ),
              const ListTile(
                title: Text("C"),
                subtitle: Text("A"),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you do not want to remove the wrapper(considering to your whole layout), you can add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` as follows. In this case, the inner list scroll is banned, and the scroll will be controlled by the wrapper `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scroll'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        // currentIndex: _selectedScreenIndex,
        // onTap: _selectScreen,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Screen A'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Screen B")
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("A"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("B"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("C"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text("C"),
                  subtitle: Text("A"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```